# Ignore autoindent in vim for one carriage return

Tags: vim

I am trying to figure out how to map the keys `<shift><cr>` to ignore smart indention for one carriage return in vim.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about, the situation maybe there is another way, and what do you mean by "the keys + to ignore …", that `+` should act as toggle key or something else.

Comment: that should make more sense. sorry i'm veryyyyyy new to vim

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
:imap <S-CR> <CR>0<C-D>
```

See

```
:help i_0_CTRL-D
```

That works when Vim is running in GUI mode. Whether it works in terminal mode depends on whether your terminal encodes Shift-Enter differently from Enter.

Answer (score -1):

Mapping [`pastetoggle`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Toggle_auto-indenting_for_code_paste) to `<S-Enter>` will probably do what you want. The [`paste`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'paste') option turns off several effect, `autoindent` just being one of them.

But if it's just `autoindent` you want, use [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Quick_generic_option_toggling):

`map   <S-Enter> :set autoindent!<CR>`

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but this is poorly worded (especially the first paragraph) and doesn't quite do what the OP wanted.

Comment: @Heptite I'm not convinced that the OP is properly expressing _exactly_ what they want. So I gave a couple of options with links to more information so the OP could educate themselves. As for being poorly worded, it's clear to me, but if it's unclear to you, why not suggest an edit?